# Wordpress: featured image else background color

Tags: wordpress, image, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to create a post that should use a featured image as background, if no image is selected it should go for a background color.

I've search around both here and Google but this code is all I could find.

```
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
else:
    $image_attributes = array( '#fa5252; opacity:1!important' ); 
endif;
?>

<div style="background: url(<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>)"></div>
```

Needless to say, it doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this ,

```
 <?php
 $background = '';
 if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );
    $background = 'url('.$image_attributes[0].')'; 
else:
    $image_attributes = array( ' ' ); 
    $background = '#fa5252; opacity:1!important';
endif;
?>

<div style="background: <?php echo $background ; ?>">Content</div>
```